# CSS: div borders appear to have shading

Tags: css, border, background-image

I have 3 divs floating next to each other in a containing div. The leftmost div and the middle div both have a border on the right. Each of the divs has a background image. As you can see in the picture, the two (right) borders appear to be darker in the middle and lighter on the top and bottom.[image]

When I remove the background images from the middle div, the borders appear to have less shading.[image]

And when I take away all three background images, the borders appear a solid color, like the CSS indicates they should be.

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are seeing is an optical illusion. look at the colors in MSPaint.

Comment: Yup, similar to this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grey_square_optical_illusion.PNG

Comment: Yep, both sets of borders are indeed #C2CA55.

Comment: Wooh art class in highschool paid off!